# Firebase Remote Config using Python

Tags: python, kivy, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to create a kivy app and I am wondering how can I use firebase remote config in my app. Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App

class screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(screen1,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=2)
        self.add_widget(layout)
        label = Label(text="Hello there!", color=(0,1,1,1))
        layout.add_widget(label)

class app (App):
    def build(self):
        screenmanager = ScreenManager()
        screenmanager.add_widget(screen1(name='screen1'))

        return screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().run()`
```

Goal: I want to change the color of the current label and then add a second label2 saying "Thank you".

I have created the parameters and conditions in the Firebase console but I am not sure how to integrate this with my code.

I have tried following Firebase tutorials, however, most of them are conducted in Java or Javascript. Please feel free to suggest tutorials or readings that can help me get started with Firebase-remote-config in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that your requirement is impossible for now.

As in the [Firebase Remote Config Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started), there is no clue about Python support.

If we want to use Python and Feature Flags (the idea behind Firebase Remote Config), Firebase Remote Config is not an available pair.